# github api authentication with javascript

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, github

I'm trying to access data from repos on the github api and I've reached the limit and now need to authenticate to increase my limit. I'm trying to authentocate via the headers in my application and I've used the following in my header:

```
    var headers= {'User-Agent':'pen.js',
                 'authToken' : 'mytoken',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
```

But I keep on getting 403 as a response from the server. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct format for specifying the headers. Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way:

```
{'User-Agent':'pen.js',
  type: 'oauth',
  key: 'your key',
  secret: 'your secret'}
```

You can get your key & secret generated in your github profile -> applications.

Let me know if there are any questions with this!